# Xamarin Forms Display Alert Disappear

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

i'm developing an app in Xamarin Forms, but i've noticed a strange behavior, when i display an alert, in Android (version major than 4.2.2), if i press outside the alert modal, the alert disappear immediately. There is any way to prevent this? I want that the alert disappear only on user selection.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

When a dialog is shown in Android, clicking just outside of it to cancel is pretty standard. To change this behavior you will need to create an interface in your PCL:

```
public interface ICustomAlert
{
  void ShowAlert(string message);
}
```

In your Android project create the implementation (something like this):

```
  [assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (AndroidCustomAlert))]   
  public class AndroidCustomAlert : ICustomAlert
    {
      void ShowAlert(string message)
      {
        var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context);
        builder.SetMessage(message);
        builder.SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) => { });
        builder.SetCancelable(false);
        builder.Show();
      }
    }
```

Notice the `SetCancelable(false)`. That's what makes it so the user can't click outside of the alert and make it disappear.

To use it, get ICustomAlert from the dependency service and call ShowAlert:

```
DependencyService.Get<ICustomAlert>().ShowAlert("Hello!");
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but my app crash: "Android.Views.WindowManagerBadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application". Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I wasn't in my IDE when typing that out. The issue was in AndroidCustomAlert's AlertDialog.Builder. It needs the context. Get it from Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context instead of Application.Context.

What's important is that you understand the DependencyService and the SetCancelable(false).

Comment: @AndreaMarinoni I believe this answers your question. Did the updated answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own DisplayAlert with a PopupLayout.

***OR***

Make use of [**ACR User Dialogs Plugin for Xamarin**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Acr.UserDialogs/) by **Allan Ritchie**