# PRISM (Xamarin Forms) IPageDialogService DisplayAlertAsync is not Modal?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have a Prism/Forms application running on Android 11 and I am using the IPageDialogService.DisplayAlertAsync method to popup a question to the user.

Problem is, if the user clicks on the page content behind the popup (basically, anywhere outside of the popup) the popup is dismissed.

Is this normal? According to the documentation [here](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/maui/dialogs/pagedialogs.html),

> The DisplayAlertAsync method shows a modal pop-up to alert the user or
> ask simple questions of them

My understanding of "Modal", is that it is foremost and no other interaction can take place until it is cleared; not the behaviour I am seeing.

I had never noticed this behaviour before, but now it is causing a problem.

Forms v5.0.0.2578
Prism v8.1.97
DryIoc v4.7.7

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be an issue with this specific version of prism?

Comment: @FreakyAli I don't think so; I have found a couple of other articles that show this behaviour as having been there for some time (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40339059/xamarin-forms-display-alert-disappear for example)

Comment: I mean XF's Display Alert is not modal though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups

Comment: @FreakyAli that is true, until today I did not really realise that IPageDialogService was just a wrapper around the base XF implementation; I may have to look at alternatives!

Comment: It's ok, you could use [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup)

Comment: At least in xamarin for android, clicking outside the popup dismisses the dialog, same does the back button. A dialog should always be prepared for the user just closing it without answering either yes or no, I suppose.

Comment: @FreakyAli Yes I could, but I think I may choose https://github.com/aritchie/userdialogs/tree/v7.2.0 instead.

Comment: @Haukinger Perhaps, but when you click outside of the popup it reacts as a "Cancel". Personally I think the popups should be modal and require the user to click/tap one of the available options.

Comment: That is the design of the pop-up in the prism. You can try to use the other pop-up elements. Xamarin also provide some Pop-ups elements. You can check this [Display Pop-ups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups).

Comment: the user can always tap the back button, it may be a hardware button even, to cancel the popup - no way can you have a popup without a cancel functionality (and not disturb your user). that said, I'm with you that "tap outside to cancel" is not always nice, if you want to hide the possibility of cancellation...